# BackBone parse json collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections

Please help to solve problem. I need to get some data from json files, but when i parse, i have error like: **Uncaught Error: A "collection" property must be specified**

my collection code:

```
var myColl = new Backbone.Collection({
    defaults: {
        model: MyModel
    },
    model: MyModel,
    url: 'json/collection.json',
    parse: function(response){
        return response.items;
    }
});
```

Comment: Backbone.js doesn't throw such a exception. What else are you using? Is another framework involved that uses Backbone under the hood?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know why backbone.js is throwing such error. Anyways, make sure you're doing/ fulfilling the following steps...

1. Since you use a normal variable, unlike window variable for collection placeholder, So your collection, model all should come together in a single file.
2. Well when you declare a collection, probably you should end up in extending the backbone collection from underscore/backbone library.
   For that you should be having

   var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   ...

   Find the .extend which is appended in your collection declaration.
3. And make sure that the collection url, returns a collection when you make a server call(post,get,update,delete) in the parse method. You can verify this using postman plugin in chrome, restclient plugin in firefox.

If the above steps are not helpful, please provide more information on your question.